# I want a sidebar to display only on the homepage on a WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a novice programmer with only a basic knowledge of PHP. I just want to get parts of a sidebar to display only on the homepage on this WordPress site.  I'm also not the one who originally wrote this code.

```
<?php // include_once('editor.php'); ?>

<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar') ) : ?>

    <div class="widget">
        <h4><span><?php _e('Sidebar', 'oldpaper') ?></span></h4>
        <p><?php _e('Use the Admin widget page to populate the sidebar.', 'oldpaper') ?></p>
```

The rest of the code is essentially the same just with different content in each part of the sidebar.  If I need to provide more of the code I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out what conditional tag to use.

Go to Settings -> Reading in your administration.

- If your "Front page" and "Posts page" are set to "-- select --", you should use the is_home() conditional tag.
- if your "Front Page" is set to a particular page, then your conditional tag is is_front_page()
- if your "Posts Page" is set to a particular page, and "Front Page" is "-- select --", your conditional tag is is_home()

Then, you should use that conditional tag and wrap your sidebar in a PHP if block with that conditional tag. So if your conditional tag is is_home(), it would become like this:

```
<?php 
if (is_home()) {
    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar') ) {
        ?>
        <div class="widget">
            <h4><span><?php _e('Sidebar', 'oldpaper') ?></span></h4>
            <p><?php _e('Use the Admin widget page to populate the sidebar.', 'oldpaper') ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```